# How can I update the context cached in OrionLD (mongoDB)?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How can I make OrionLD recognize when I update the content of a context file referenced by OrionLD?

In previous versions of OrionLD, you could get the latest context by restarting OrionLD.
However, with the implementation of the Persist context cache feature, it is no longer possible to overwrite the context information.
(https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/pull/844)

Is there any way to do this?

I restarted OrionLD and mongoDB, but
OrionLD and mongoDB were restarted, but the latest context was not recognized.
Do I need to manually delete the document in mongoDB where the context information is stored?

■My environment
・Orion
　 ：fiware/orion-ld:latest
　　　　　(post-v0.8.1)
・Mongo
　：mongo:3.6

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. We recently defined how this is to work in ETSI ISG CIM, the workgroup that defines the NGSI-LD API. It's not public yet, but I will try to implement this asap anyway. As of right now, yeah, I'm afraid a manual delete from mongo is the only way to do it.

WAIT ...

I did implement the DELETE request on cached contexts. For that you'll need the local identifier (GET /ngsi-ld/v1/jsonldContexts). Once you have the local identifier you can ask the broker to DELETE the context and after that, it will be downloaded anew.
It's a pretty good "workaround" until I implement the "overwrite" option for cached contexts.

Comment: [ it worked before, as the broker didn't persist the cache and the cache was thus "reset" on restart of the broker ]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.
I understand about the definition in NGSI-LD API.

And, thanks for telling me about the jsonldContexts API.
I've confirmed that the DELETE API works.
(GET /ngsi-ld/v1/jsonldContexts retrieved URLs instead of IDs, so I went directly to mongoDB to get IDs and used them.

I understood that I need to delete the cache manually at this point, so that was helpful.

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Try `GET /ngsi-ld/v1/jsonldContexts?details=true`. With that you get more info, including the local ID. No need to turn to mongo.